# Getting values from wpdb

Tags: wpdb

I'm trying to get values from columns `name` and `id`. Could Anyone tell me how can I get these two values in loop, and adjust this sql for Wordpress?

```
function get_calendar_ids() {

    global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
Select
  wp_calendars.user_id,
  wp_calendars.name,
  wp_calendars.id
From
  wp_calendars
Where
  wp_calendars.user_id = '$user_id'
");
$calendars = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
     if ($calendars ) {
        return $calendars;
        echo $sql;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not too far away from your goal. The `get_calendar_ids` must return only `$calendars`.

In your function `$wpdb->get_results( $sql )` will return an object with the datas your asked.

```
function get_calendar_ids() {

    global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
    Select
      wp_calendars.user_id,
      wp_calendars.name,
      wp_calendars.id
    From
      wp_calendars
    Where
      wp_calendars.user_id = '$user_id'
");
    $calendars = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
     if ($calendars ) {
        return $calendars;          
     }
}
```

Your function now return an object with only user_id, name, and id, the result must in a loop to echo the result, you can grab them like this $calendar->name in a foreach loop.

an example in a shortcode,

```
add_shortcode('calendars', 'get_calendars');

function get_calendar($atts, $content = ""){

    // you can add $atts extract_args if need

    $calendars = get_calendar_ids();

    if($calendars){
        foreach($calendars as $calendar){
            $user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($calendar->id).'">'.$calendar->name . '</a> by '.$user_data->user_nicename.'</br>';

        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! It works, but `$wpdb->prepare` needs parameter, so I made function get_calendar_ids($user_id) and got it in shortcode. Second question - most of wpdb calls are not using prefix `wp_` how can I change it here?

Comment: You can get the prefix with : $wpdb->prefix.calendars

Comment: I mean,  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'calendars'; before $sql and get $table_name for the FROM.